# New Excel file with different format want to import data to sql table using ssis

Tags: ssis

this is my file please tell me how can I insert date and price
cell `C4` and `C21` into table 
please help
I took `excel source and sets`OpenRowSet`property to`SHEET$C4:C21`
but which is giving me only one column and invalid data also 
please help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this using a script task in your package. But consider using SSRS instead. I think this is what SSRS made for.

With SSRS you can make a report using BIDS or also you can create a local report with Visual Studio inside of an (e.g.) ASP.NET application. With the ASP.NET ReportViewer component you can visualize your report and export it to Excel as well. You can even export programmatically if you should do this.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ReportViewer.aspx) is a tutorial how to use SSRS together with ASP.NET ReportViewer. [Another](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/viral/archive/2010/07/09/generating-ssrs-reports-programatically.aspx) turorial for how to use exporting functionality.

Comment: please elaborate with example or tell me what should be the `'OpenRowSet'` property of `'Excel source'`