# Not able to insert merge values in one row using ssis?

Tags: ssis

I have two `excel source` on `one excel file` 1st fetching value `date` and 2nd fetching value `price`
now i have tried `merge` then `union all` also to get those two values in one `derived column` 
but when i execute my package it is inserting values separately.
like this into two rows one by one but i want to insert these two values in one row only.

for example this is my problem:

`date            price

 12-12-2001      null`

`date         price

 null         54`

but i want it in one row only like

`date         price

 12-12-2001   54`

[image]

Comment: And how would you know what price goes with waht date if the are on separate rows?

Comment: actually i don't want any selection I JUST WANT TO TAKE 'DATE' and 'PRICE' from one excel file these 2 values are there.
please look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/7482470/428073

Comment: yes i did that now i'm having 2 values which is coming from source 1 and source2 and sort it but problem is these two values are inserted into table one by one

Comment: @ashuthinks - Glad to see you were able to solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two derived columns with the same value (i.e. call them id1 and id2 and set both to have a value of 1).

Change the sort to sort by the new id columns.

Change the merge component to a merge join and use the newly created ids to link the data based on an inner join

[image: SSIS Merge Join]

which will give you a single row

[image: Data flow for single row]

Comment: When I'm using `MERGE JOIN` giving error like `TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

`Both inputs of the transformation must contain at least one sorted column, and those columns must have matching metadata.
`

Comment: You need to change both Sort and Sort1 to sort on your new derived column and pass through the OLE DB Source value